# How to switch between different chrome browser window opened by different WebDriver using selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I searched for this question,and I found an idea using driver.switch_to.window(),but it didn't work as expect:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver1=webdriver.Chrome("D:\Python\Files\chromedriver.exe")
driver1.get('https://www.google.com')


driver2=webdriver.Chrome("D:\Python\Files\chromedriver.exe")
driver2.get('https://www.bing.com/')

driver1.switch_to.window(driver1.current_window_handle)
```

above code will first open a chrome window and go to google,then will open another chrome window and go to bing,then

```
driver1.switch_to.window(driver1.current_window_handle)
```

seems didn't work,the window showing bing still shows on top of the window showing google.
Anyone have any idea?I think

```
driver1.switch_to.window(driver1.current_window_handle)
```

may have some BUG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have used two *WebDriver* instances as **driver1** and **driver2** respectively to openthe urls https://www.google.com (e.g. windowA) and https://www.bing.com/ (e.g. windowB) it is worth to mention that the function [`switch_to.window()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) is a *WebDriver* method. So, *driver1* can control only *windowA* and *driver2* can control only *windowB*.

For *Selenium* to interact with any of the *Browsing Window*, *Selenium* needs **focus**. So to iterate among the different *Browsing Windows* you can shift the focus to the different *Browsing Window* using *JavascriptExecutor* as follows :

- *Python*:

  ```
  driver1.execute_script("window.focus();")
  driver2.execute_script("window.focus();")
  ```
- *Java*:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver1).executeScript("window.focus();");
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver2).executeScript("window.focus();");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a different concept of "window" in driver.switch_to.window(). In chrome browser, it means "tab". It's not another chrome browser or browser window like what are you trying to do in your code.

If switch_to.window() what you really want, I'll give an example how to use it:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome("D:\Python\Files\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
# open a new tab with js
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.bing.com')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
# now your driver is pointed to the "tab" you just opened
```

Comment: Thanks.I misunderstood what 'switch_to_window' mean,it will switch between tabs in the same webdriver.But what I really what is to switch between different webdriver window,do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a way to jump to different instances of chrome? In other words I have one instance of Chrome open as a particular user and another instance of Chrome running for another user and I want to be able to call either instance. I didn't see a mention of instances on https://pypi.org/project/selenium/. Thank you for any advice you can give.