# I am trying to switch between 2 browser windows using 2 different users for testing in Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

For my test using Selenium and Python, I need to open 2 sessions of the browser with 2 users and check updates are made in the other window when changes are made in window 1.
I am able to open a 2nd session with a different user by opening it as chrome incognito mode but am not sure how to switch back and forth between the 2 open browser sessions.

I have tried the following extract as an example, but as the 2nd window is a new window using `driver.get` again the `[-1]` does not appear to take the focus back to `window_before`:

```
window_after = driver.window_handles[0]
print('windows after', window_after)
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Comment: Please share the whole code in which you are opening  2 sessions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch between different chrome browser window opened by different WebDriver using selenium in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216418/how-to-switch-between-different-chrome-browser-window-opened-by-different-webdri)

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate a second driver for the second user session:

```py
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
```

All of the windows for a particular driver instance share the same cookies; therefore, you can’t open a new window and expect to create a second user session. The second window will “see” the same cookies as the first, causing them to be sent to your website, wherein your app will see the visitor as already logged in under the first user session.

Creating a second driver instance gives you a second, isolated pool of cookies (as well as local and session storage), allowing you to safely and reliably create a second user session.

While you may have found a way to open an incognito/private window within the same driver instance, this is not supported by the WebDriver specification (on which Selenium is built) and thus is unlikely to be portable across browsers and platforms.

---

[capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py) makes this easy—transparently instantiating a new driver instance as needed:

```py
import capybara

def test_concurrent_editors(page):
    page.visit("/")
    page.click_link("Sign In")
    page.fill_in("Username", value="alice@example.com")
    page.fill_in("Password", value="s33krit")
    page.click_button("Sign In")

    # ... do things with the default session

    with capybara.using_session("other user"):
        page.visit("/")
        page.click_link("Sign In")
        page.fill_in("Username", value="bob@example.com")
        page.fill_in("Password", value="p@ssw0rd")
        page.click_button("Sign In")

        # ... do things with the "other user" session

    # .... do more things with the default session

    with capybara.using_session("other user"):
        # ... do more things with the "other user" session
```

(Note: It comes with a pytest plugin that exposes the `page` fixture and resets all sessions in between each test.)

Comment: I am setting up the driver in the fixture so that driver can be passed in  as a parameter do you know a neat way of passing 2 instances of the driver for 1 test

Comment: @pytest.fixture()
def driver():
    return webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/....

Comment: You can define a second fixture for that, specifying both as arguments to the test functions that require it. But I also included some information on capybara-py, a library that makes it so you don't even have to think about that.