# Selenium VBA two instances at the same time

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I have searched for such a topic but didn't find a clue to start with. I am using selenium in VBA and I have some numbers which I will search in column A
Is it possible to divide those numbers into two parts (example: the numbers are 100 so it would be divided into two parts and each part has 50 numbers). Maybe an array to hold the numbers. This is not the problem (I am just imagining the scenario)
Then open two drivers or bots and each bot deals with each part

```
Private bot1 As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Private bot2 As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
```

How to make both bots run at the same time in VBA?

Answer (score 2):

You can always initiate two bots as:

```
Private bot1 As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Private bot2 As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
```

shift the [focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521886/7429447) to either of the instances depending on your requirement as follows:

- Focusing on *`bot1`*:

  ```
  bot1.ExecuteScript "window.focus();"
  ```
- Focusing on *`bot2`*:

  ```
  bot2.ExecuteScript "window.focus();"
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the bots will run at the same time or what?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Yeap, they can run at the same time. The _`session ID`_ would be different.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out. Can you put an example, please?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49220645/7429447) discussion.