# Having multiple concurrent Selenium Webdriver sessions connected to the same chrome headless process

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

Is there a way to have one chromedriver process instance running but have two different Selenium WebDrivers connected to it where both run code at the same time? (e.g. navigate to a URL, click on a button, ...)?

I know that I can open two different pages on the same headless browser and switch between them, but I want to do both processings simultaneously, so that won't work for me.

I'm writing this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate two [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *browsing context* simultaneously as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver1.get("https://www.google.com");

WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver2.get("https://www.bing.com/");
```

and [switch focus between them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49220645/7429447) as follows:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver1).executeScript("window.focus();");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver2).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

Comment: But this starts "two" chrome headless processes

Comment: _concurrent Selenium Webdriver sessions_: For concurrent Selenium Webdriver sessions there should be session(**s**), multiple.

Comment: I'm ok with having multiple sessions. I just want a single "process".